# Any examples for such an AIR application

Tags: apache-flex, firefox, adobe, air

I'm looking for an example of an AIR application, that all it does it loads Firefox. Can someone point me to an example that can be modified to do this, or that does this exactly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mx:WindowedApplication xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml" layout="absolute">
<mx:Script><![CDATA[
import flash.net.URLRequest;

public function clickButton():void{
var request : URLRequest = new URLRequest('C:\\path to mozilla\firefox.exe');
navigateToURL(request )    
}
]]></mx:Script>

<mx:Button click="clickButton()" label="Launch Firefox"/>
</mx:WindowedApplication>
```

if not sure about location or on mac
use properties like this to get to default folders..

```
var appDir:File    = File.applicationDirectory;
var appStoreDir:File= File.applicationStorageDirectory;
var desktopDir:File = File.desktopDirectory;
var docDir:File    = File.documentsDirectory;
var userDir:File    = File.userDirectory;
var rootDirArr:Array = File.getRootDirectories();
```